# Pycharm keeps giving name 'class' is not defined error

Tags: python

I have tried to see every possible solution for this but for some reason none of them have worked. I am doing *Learn Python the Hard way* exercise 49. I made my own parser and it works when I run it via pycharm, when i open the console or powershell and try to import, it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'parse_sentence' is not defined
```

I also tried to see if the problem is in the script, so I copied his work down onto another tab and it gave me the same problem.

Here a little bit of my code:

```
class Sentence:

def __init__(self, type):
    self.type = type


def subjects(self):
    nouns = ('door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet')

    s = self.scan(self.type)
    for i in s:
        for k in i:
            if k in nouns:
                print k

def verbs(self):
    verbs = ('go', 'stop', 'kill', 'eat', 'open')
    s = self.scan(self.type)
    for i in s:
        for k in i:
            if k in verbs:
                print k

def objects(self):
    directions = ('north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'left', 'right', 'back')
    nouns = ('door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet')
    s = self.scan(self.type)
    for i in s:
        for k in i:
            if k in directions or k in nouns:
                print k

def get_tuple(self, word):

    directions = ('north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'left', 'right', 'back')
    verbs = ('go', 'stop', 'kill', 'eat', 'open')
    stop_words = ('the', 'in', 'of', 'from', 'at', 'it')
    nouns = ('door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet')

    lowercased = word.lower()

    if lowercased in directions:
        return ('direction', lowercased)
    elif lowercased in verbs:
        return ('verb', lowercased)
    elif lowercased in stop_words:
        return ('stop_words', lowercased)
    elif lowercased in nouns:
        return ('noun', lowercased)
    elif lowercased.isdigit():
        return ('number', int(lowercased))
    else:
        return ('error', word)


def scan(self, sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    return [self.get_tuple(word) for word in words]
```

it is not because of the `self.scan`, it is in the class I just don't want to post all of the code to not mess the page up. I open console, i type `import parser` (parser is the name of this file) that works, then it i type `myarg = Sentence('let us kill the bear')`. gives me the error up above. Samehting when I do his way, thank you so much for reading this in advance.

I am on Windows 10, Python 2.7

Here is my error

```
import parser
myarg = Sentence('let us kill the bear')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Sentence' is not defined
```

when doing 
    import paser
    parser.Sentence()

I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Sentence'
```

when doing :

```
import parser
myarg = parser.Sentence('let us kill the bear')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Sentence'
```

Comment: I will add the rest of the code if anyone needs it

Comment: always in question show full error message (Traceback) There are other usefull information - ie. which line makes problem. I don't see `parse_sentence` in your code.

Comment: Hello furas, thank you for replying. I aplogoize I forgot to copy my error. That was the error i got when trying to do Zed Shaw's parser example. here is the full code :

Comment: import parser
myarg = Sentence('let us kill the bear')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Sentence' is not defined

Comment: LPTHW is terrible, by the way.

Comment: alway add code and errors in question, not in comment - it will be more readable.

Comment: I meant to say here is the error i get up above but it is not letting me edit

Comment: Tigerhawk I know but was told about that when I was already at ex 43, I might aswell finish it

Comment: if you do `import parser` then you have to use  `parser.Sentence()`

Comment: I edited what i get from that furas

Comment: what do you have in file `parser.py` ? Do you have class `Sentence` in `parser.py` ?

Comment: Yes sir, would you like me to post my entire script?

Comment: maybe your  `parser.py` is in different folder and maybe Python has `parser` module in its library so it import module from library instead of your file.

Comment: you can try `import parser` and later `print(parser.__file__)` to see which file is imported.

Comment: So I add this in answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you import

```
import parser
```

then you have to use `parser.Sentence()`

```
myarg = parser.Sentence('let us kill the bear')
```

If you import

```
from parser import Sentence
```

then you can use `Sentence()`

```
myarg = Sentence('let us kill the bear')
```

---

Python first looks for file in "current working directory" ("cwd"). If you run code in different folder then it can import from library module with the same name instead of your file.

You can check what file was imported

```
 import parser

 print(parser.__file__)
```

To check current working directory

```
 import os

 print(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: when trying to do from parser import Sentence, it says can not import name Sentence

Comment: do you have `class Sentence` in file `parser.py` ?

Comment: would you like me to post more?

Comment: Okay i just did it

Comment: Also @Omar, you don't have to call us sir. You welcome to just call us by our usernames. eg. _furas_ instead of _sir_ or _leaf_ instead of _sir_ :)